# Where is "reopen closed tab" menu option on Google Chrome 78

Tags: google-chrome

I have recently updated to Google Chrome 78 and noticed that the option to reopen closed tab has disappeared from menu that appears when you right click on any tab. Now I have to use the much further away `Three dots button` > `History`.

Is there a way to put the option back on the tab menu?

I'm aware of the <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> keybind, however I would like to also have an option using the mouse.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You now need to click outside the tab area. On the right side of the opened tabs.

[image]

Comment: Note that CTRL-click/tap on the MacBook trackpad does not seem to trigger this context menu. You need to enable some other form of "secondary click" in System Preferences. This can be confusing, since ctrl-click works everywhere else in Chrome. Right-click on an external mouse works fine.

Comment: @MarcEnglund You do a right click on the trackpad by using two fingers instead of one. I think Ctrl+click is a different menu.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answer, another option is clicking the three vertical dots to the right:

> [image]

Then expand the History item and you can choose which tabs to reopen:

> [image]

Answer (score 1):

## Extension [*Reopen closed tab Button™*](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/reopen-closed-tab-button/jjchodckpgecejjbbdedboikbidieebe)
• 1 click

• preserves the tab’s **history**

[image]
[image]

(It also offers a context menu item:)
[image]

Because I tend to have a lot of tabs open, I find this extension’s button much more efficient (than first aiming for the small corner of empty tab bar and then for the context menu item for the second click).

It does exactly the same as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>: undo closing the last° closed tab, restoring the tab’s history (`←` *go back* button).
° recursively: clicking n times will reopen the n last closed tabs

This is the only extension I could find that does this – all the others pop up a menu, so you need 2 clicks.  If you want that: [SimpleUndoRecents](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/simpleundorecents/kaiblbjjcealhldhdnjhpjmckgclnbca) seemed the most powerful among the 2-click-menu type extensions:
[image]
[image]

Unfortunately, there is no extension yet that restores the exact functionality of providing the item in the *tab context menu*, because Chrome’s API doesn’t support that.<sup>[1]</sup>

<sub>[1] source: some reddit [comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/chrome/comments/e0g1by/looking_for_extension_to_replace_reopen_closed/f8e4hr9/)</sub>